# Appium : Element not identified during test run

Tags: appium, appium-android

I have obtained locators using appium inspector . The obtained element works well during recording in appium inspector. But when I run the test case, appium fails to identify the element.
Below is the log in the server

```
    [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST 
    http://127.0.0.1:8000/wd/hub/session] with body: {"desiredCapabilities":{"chromeOptions":{"androidPackage":"com.android.chrome","androidDeviceSerial":"3208c623a27f61e9"}}}
[Chromedriver] Webview version: 'Chrome/63.0.3239.111'
[JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"a577f16ef658470ccbc8066131f27b70","status":0,"value":{"acceptSslCerts":true,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"browserName":"chrome","chrome":{"chromedriverVersion":"2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f)"},"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"handlesAlerts":true,"hasTouchScreen":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":true,"mobileEmulationEnabled":false,"nativeEvents":true,"pageLoadStrategy":"normal","platform":"ANDROID","rotatable":false,"setWindowRect":false,"takesHeapSnapshot":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"unexpectedAlertBehaviour":"","version":"63.0.3239.111","webStorageEnabled":true}}
[Chromedriver] Changed state to 'online'
[Appium] New AndroidDriver session created successfully, session 9aa0ede8-867f-41a1-b4c9-61416598aaf0 added to master session list
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1542707446213 (15:20:46 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.createSession() result: {"platform":"LINUX","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"browserName":"chrome","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"3208c623a27f61e9"},"browserName":"chrome","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"3208c623a27f61e9","deviceUDID":"3208c623a27f61e9","platformVersion":"6.0.1","deviceScreenSize":"1080x1920","deviceModel":"SM-G900H","deviceManufacturer":"samsung"}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 200 33062 ms - 584 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/9aa0ede8-867f-41a1-b4c9-61416598aaf0/url {"url":"https://www.google.com"}
[MJSONWP] Driver proxy active, passing request on via HTTP proxy
[JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /wd/hub/session/9aa0ede8-867f-41a1-b4c9-61416598aaf0/url] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/wd/hub/session/a577f16ef658470ccbc8066131f27b70/url] with body: {"url":"https://www.google.com"}
[JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"a577f16ef658470ccbc8066131f27b70","status":0,"value":null}
[JSONWP Proxy] Replacing sessionId a577f16ef658470ccbc8066131f27b70 with 9aa0ede8-867f-41a1-b4c9-61416598aaf0
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/9aa0ede8-867f-41a1-b4c9-61416598aaf0/url 200 4603 ms - 76 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/9aa0ede8-867f-41a1-b4c9-61416598aaf0/element {"using":"xpath","value":"/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View[3]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[3]"}
[MJSONWP] Driver proxy active, passing request on via HTTP proxy
[JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /wd/hub/session/9aa0ede8-867f-41a1-b4c9-61416598aaf0/element] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/wd/hub/session/a577f16ef658470ccbc8066131f27b70/element] with body: {"using":"xpath","value":"/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View[3]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[3]"}
[JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"a577f16ef658470ccbc8066131f27b70","status":7,"value":{"message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"method\":\"xpath\",\"selector\":\"/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View[3]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[3]\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.111)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)"}}
[JSONWP Proxy] Replacing sessionId a577f16ef658470ccbc8066131f27b70 with 9aa0ede8-867f-41a1-b4c9-61416598aaf0
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/9aa0ede8-867f-41a1-b4c9-61416598aaf0/element 200 205 ms - 733 
[HTTP] --> DELETE /wd/hub/session/9aa0ede8-867f-41a1-b4c9-61416598aaf0 {}
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.deleteSession() with args: ["9aa0ede8-867f-41a1-b4c9-61416598aaf0"]
[BaseDriver] Event 'quitSessionRequested' logged at 1542707451117 (15:20:51 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[Appium] Removing session 9aa0ede8-867f-41a1-b4c9-61416598aaf0 from our master session list
[AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
[AndroidDriver] Stopping chromedriver for context CHROMIUM
[Chromedriver] Changed state to 'stopping'
[JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [DELETE /] to [DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8000/wd/hub/session/a577f16ef658470ccbc8066131f27b70] with no body
[JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: "{\"sessionId\":\"a577f16ef658470ccbc8066131f27b70\",\"status\":0,\"value\":null}"
[Chromedriver] Changed state to 'stopped'
```

Comment: possibly can be a wait issue

Comment: Added sufficient wait times. Doesn't seem to work even while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that your screen's element is not available when you tried to interact with that element. If you tried to use implicit wait, it didn't work for me.

You can use **explicit wait** or **Thread.sleep()**.

> Thread.sleep() is not recommended way.

you can use explicit wait using following method:

```
 public void ExplicitWait(MobileElement element,int timeOutInSeconds) {
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds)).until(ExpectedConditions
                .visibilityOf(element));
    }
```